# Java validation XSD schema with includes

Tags: java, xml, resources, xsd, include

setup:

java file, scrap code

```
   SchemaFactory customSchemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1");
   customSchemaFactory.setResourceResolver(new XSDResourceResolver());
   Source customSchemaSource = new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/customXSD.xsd"));
   Schema customSchema  = customSchemaFactory.newSchema(customSchemaSource);
   Validator customValidator = customSchema.newValidator();
   Source source = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
   customValidator.validate(source);
```

XSDResouceResolver looks exactly like this (classic generic resolver) -
http://pbin.oogly.co.uk/listings/viewlistingdetail/2a70d763929ce3053085bfaa1d78e2

customXSD.xsd is classic XSD file with several imports, the one particular bothering me is MathML schema:

```
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" schemaLocation="/path/to/mathml3.xsd"/>
```

this schema by default contains includes:

```
   <xs:include schemaLocation="mathml3-content.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="mathml3-presentation.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="mathml3-common.xsd"/>
```

Everything is going well if I comment out the includes and left just the import of MathML schema with commented body. But if includes are present, there are bunch of exceptions like this one (probably exactly four as there are four includes in all schemas) originated from:

```
customSchema = customSchemaFactory.newSchema(customSchemaSource);

java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(Unknown Source)
    at ...validation.XSDResourceResolver$LSInputImpl.getStringData(XSDResourceResolver.java:63)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.DOMEntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchemaSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.BaseSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
```

I've tried so far:

- rename all include locations to /path/to/mathml3-content.xsd etc. (because imports with this /path/to are working, including mathml3.xsd itself)
- change includes to imports just as they are, I wasn't expecting that to work and it didn't, :)
- paste all included content to mathml3.xsd itself, it was pretty huge, and it gave me ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Question is - Is there any way to resolve stream errors with schemas which include another schemas? (not imports, they work). I think I'm just missing something important. Maybe it's related to resources paths/locations? (buts imports are working normally, all XSDs are in same folder/path one next to other)

Comment: Broken link? http://pbin.oogly.co.uk/listings/viewlistingdetail/2a70d763929ce3053085bfaa1d78e2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your implementation of `LSInput` is flawed.

Replacing

```
@Override
public InputStream getByteStream() {            
    return null;
}
```

with

```
@Override
public InputStream getByteStream() {
    return inputStream;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public String getStringData() {
    synchronized (inputStream) {
        try {
            byte[] input = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            inputStream.read(input);
            String contents = new String(input);
            return contents;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
@Override
public String getStringData() {
    return null;
}
```

fixes the error in my test setup.